# IncompatibleSchemaException: Unexpected type VectorUDT when serializing in Avro format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, avro, spark-avro

I am using Spark Mllib to generate predictions for my data and then store them to HDFS in Avro format:

```
val dataPredictions = myModel.transform(myData)
val output = dataPredictions.select("is", "probability", "prediction")
output.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save(path)
```

I am getting the following Exception:

```
com.databricks.spark.avro.SchemaConverters$IncompatibleSchemaException:
    Unexpected type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7.
```

My understanding is that the 'prediction' column format cannot be serialized as Avro.

- How do I convert a VectorUDT into an Array so that I can serialize it in Avro?
- Are there any better alternatives (I can't move away from Avro format)?

Answer (score 2):

To convert any `Vector` to an `Array[Double]` you can use the following UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector

val vectorToArrayUdf = udf((vector: Vector) => vector.toArray)

// The following will work
val output = dataPredictions
    .withColumn("probabilities", vectorToArrayUdf(col("probability")))
    .select("id", "probabilities", "prediction")

output.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save(path)
```